# Changing endianness in PHP

Tags: php, file-format, endianness

So i'm making a class in PHP to parse the [VPK](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/VPK_File_Format) file format.

However i've hit a problem:

```
object(VPKHeader)#2 (3) {
    ["Signature"]=>
  string(8) "3412aa55"
    ["Version"]=>
  string(4) "1000"
    ["DirectoryLength"]=>
  int(832512)
}
```

The signature is supposed to be 0x55aa1234, however the signature I'm reading is 0x3412aa55.

How do I switch the endianness in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your hex values will always be strings, you can use the following function :

```
function swapEndianness($hex) {
    return implode('', array_reverse(str_split($hex, 2)));
}
```

Agreed, it's not the most efficient, but the code is quite elegant in my opinion. Also, it works with all sizes of numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did it! I tried every method under the sun to try and cast the hex digits but to no avail. Your method works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the value manually. The algorithm will be the same as it is in C++, so just port this code (you only need the one that works on `int` afaik):

```
inline void endian_swap(unsigned short& x)
{
    x = (x>>8) | 
        (x<<8);
}

// this is the one you need
inline void endian_swap(unsigned int& x)
{
    x = (x>>24) | 
        ((x<<8) & 0x00FF0000) |
        ((x>>8) & 0x0000FF00) |
        (x<<24);
}

// __int64 for MSVC, "long long" for gcc
inline void endian_swap(unsigned __int64& x)
{
    x = (x>>56) | 
        ((x<<40) & 0x00FF000000000000) |
        ((x<<24) & 0x0000FF0000000000) |
        ((x<<8)  & 0x000000FF00000000) |
        ((x>>8)  & 0x00000000FF000000) |
        ((x>>24) & 0x0000000000FF0000) |
        ((x>>40) & 0x000000000000FF00) |
        (x<<56);
}
```

Source: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=292902

Comment: Was afraid of that :P I tried to port it here: http://pastebin.com/q8LtMy29 is this correct?

Comment: note that PHP doesn't support unsigned integers -- not sure how that will affect things. Also, you can find the size of the int using PHP_INT_SIZE to know which swap to use (you won't need the ushort one though)

Comment: Not exactly, it's currently showing a NULL for the signature. Here's a little example of what i'm doing: http://pastebin.com/cQnLEp1r

Comment: @anttir: everything is passed by reference, there is no need for a return statement.